# In multiple inheritance from two identical base classes, how to cast this to one of those

Tags: c++, inheritance, this, constants

I have a class that is derived from two identical bases:

```
class Vector3d {...};
class Position:public Vector3d {...};
class Velocity:public Vector3d {...};

class Trajectory:public Position, public Velocity
{
    Vector3d &GetPosition(void);
    Vector3d &GetVelocity(void);
};
```

I would like to have a member functions in derived class to quickly cast to one or the other base. What I am trying is:

```
Vector3d &GetPosition(void) const
{
    return static_cast<const Vector3d &>(*this);
}
```

but I received a kind message from the compiler: "Reference initialized with 'const Position', needs lvalue of type 'Vector3d'"

When I use:

```
const Vector3d &GetPosition(void) const
{
    return static_cast<const Vector3d &>(*this);
}
```

things compile ok but I cannot use it in the way that I intend:

```
Trajectory t;
t.Position=Set(20,30,50);
```

because t.Position is const and hence an improper lvalue, as the compiler announces.

Any ideas on how to reference base classes from this into a non constant dereference?

Comment: Not to comment on this apart from to say the design here seems somehow wrong.  It's really easy to get in a mess with inheritance.  Prefer encapsulation.  Then the problem goes away completely.

Comment: are you sure? you are running into `Diamond issue` to check it declare a member variable in the base class `Vector3d` and then call it from Trajectory's member function. so use virtual inheritance.

Comment: @Raindrop7: Do NOT use virtual inheritance here. This looks like the diamond problem, but note that for position + velocity, it is critical that those vector3d's remain 100% separate.

Comment: Why in the world would `GetPosition()` return a `Vector3d` as opposed to a `Position`? If it returns a `Position`, you get type safety, and as a bonus, the confusion for this code goes away entirely.

Answer (score 5):

You might do

```
class Trajectory:public Position, public Velocity
{
public:
    Vector3d &GetPosition() { return static_cast<Position&>(*this); }
    Vector3d &GetVelocity() { return static_cast<Velocity&>(*this); }
};
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/uSzgAp)

but using composition instead of inheritance seems more appropriate.

```
class Trajectory
{
public:
    const Position& GetPosition() const { return position; }
    Position& GetPosition() { return position; }
    const Velocity& GetVelocity() const { return velocity; }
    Velocity& GetVelocity() { return velocity; }
private:
    Position position;
    Velocity velocity;
};
```

Comment: what about diamond issue?

Comment: @Raindrop7: it is not diamond, but Y inheritance, Trajectory has 2 base vector3d, and we have to specify which one we want.

Answer (score 3):

I understand velocity is a vector (v1, v2, v3), also position is a point in 3d space (p1, p2, p3).
Now in a trajectory, a point can have both velocity and position, velocity and position are both needed. For one thing you can not use virtual inheritance.

I think composition makes more sense.

```
class Trajectory
{
    public:
    Position p;
    Velocity v;
 };
```